# How to add Featured Image to Category in Wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am new to WP and ACF and I am trying to get each category to display a featured image using a custom field set up with ACF.

I have added a field group with the location rule to show the field group if taxonomy term is equal to categories. I have then added the `<?php the_field( 'add_featured_image' ); ?>` to `single.php`

The custom field is displaying in the category options, allowing me to select a featured-image, but it is not displaying when published.

I have also tried the various different ways of targeting the ID of a single category instead of all the categories as per the ACF docs such as

```
<?php the_field( 'add_featured_image', 'category_6' ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php the_field('add_featured_image', 6); ?>
```

but nothing is working.

The nearest I have got is when using

```
<?php the_field( 'add_featured_image', 'category_6' ); ?>
```

which outputs this on the screen:

[image: This suggests something is happening but I can't figure out what is happening after plenty of trying]

I have also tried the `get_field()` function to no avail. I am using FoundationPress as a parent theme.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, go check the field settings - you can specify which value you want returned by default, an object with various properties containing information about the image, the id, or a URL, https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/#settings You can also specify this as third parameter for the_field. If you just need the URL to the default size, use that - otherwise go with the object (use var_dump to find out what properties it has, and which are of interest to you), or the id, that you can fetch into other image-fetching/-outputting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have it already with `<?php the_field( 'add_featured_image', 'category_6' ); ?>`. It's just outputting an object from which you have to get the `src`. Use `$url = $add_featured_image['url'];` and then echo it out into your image `<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>`. Same method then to get the `alt` attribute.

You'll see more [here.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Hope that helps. Best of luck!